# Convert a table into a function that can act like a Table.SelectRows condition

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have a table of `Project`:

[image]

that I would like to filter by the `FIELD`, `OPERATOR`, and `VALUE` columns contained in the `Project Group` table:

[image]

The Power Query M to apply this filter would be:

```
let
    Source = #"Project",
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Projectid", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each [Projectid] >= 100000 and [Projectid] <= 500000)
in
    #"Filtered Rows"
```

Results (need to remove the error row):

[image]

How do I convert the `FIELD`, `OPERATOR`, and `VALUE` columns into a function that can be used as a condition for the `SelectRows` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to do comparisons, might be best to first change the types of the columns (in both tables) that are being compared. Preferably to type `number`.

The code below assumes that:

1. the `OPERATOR` column of `Project Group` table can only contain: `>` or `<` and that these values should be interpreted as `>=` and `<=` respectively.
2. the column in `Project` table (that needs to be compared) can change and its name will be in the `FIELD` column of the `Project Group`. It's assumed that the name matches exactly. If this is not the case, you might need to standardise things (or at least perform a case-insensitive search) to ensure values can be mapped to column names correctly.

Based on the assumptions above, here's one approach:

```
let
    // Dummy table for example purposes
    project = Table.FromColumns({
        {0..10},
        {5..15}
    }, type table [projectId = number, name = number]),

    // Dummy table for example purposes
    projectGroup = Table.FromColumns({
        {"projectId", "projectId"},
        {">", "<"},
        {5, 7}
    }, type table [FIELD = text, OPERATOR = text, VALUE = number]),

    // Should take in a row from "Project" table and return a boolean
    // representing whether said row matches the criteria contained
    // within "Project Group" table.
    selectorFunc = (projectRow as record) as logical => 
        let
            shouldKeepProjectRow = Table.MatchesAllRows(projectGroup, (projectGroupRow as record) =>
                let
                    fieldNameToCheck = projectGroupRow[FIELD],
                    valueFromProjectRow = Record.Field(projectRow, fieldNameToCheck),
                    compared = if projectGroupRow[OPERATOR] = ">" then
                            valueFromProjectRow >= projectGroupRow[VALUE]
                        else
                            valueFromProjectRow <= projectGroupRow[VALUE]
                in compared
            )
        in shouldKeepProjectRow,

    selectedRows = Table.SelectRows(project, selectorFunc)
in
    selectedRows
```

The main function used is `Table.MatchesAllRows` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-matchesallrows).

---

Another approach could potentially be: `Expression.Evaluate`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/expression-evaluate. However, I've not used it, so I'm not sure whether there are any "gotchas"/implications to be aware of.